# How to show error message using .htaccess If url is incorrect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Well, I am using .htaccess rules to edit my website url structure. Now, I have following url :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones
```

This url is for zones.php page to edit a form data. After click on edit link it will go to this link :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/55
```

This link is open on `update.php` page.

Now, If I remove following part from this url

```
/55 or date/55
```

then it's showing me error message with appropriate error page. That fine.

But if I remove `update/55` from the url then url is look like that :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/ (note the forward slash at the end)
```

then it's calling zones.php page and stylesheet is broken

BUT I want to show a error page e.g : not-found.php page. How can I do this using .htaccess ?

**My .htaccess rules :**

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/aponit/dev/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/aponit/dev/404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update/(\w+)/?$ update.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /aponit/dev/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/aponit/dev/404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^zones/$ - [NC,L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update/(\w+)/?$ update.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: opps. in zones page it's showing me not fond error message

Comment: but zones.php page is exist

Comment: Normally If go to this link `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones` it's should show me the page but now it's showing me not found error message which I don't want. Error message will show when I enter this url : `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/` (note  : forward slash at the end)

Comment: what I need to do If I convert `update.php?z=55` to only `update-zone` ?

Comment: I think you should avoid adding new requirement by commenting. Isn't this answer meeting original problem of showing 404 page for `/zones/` URI?

Comment: Okey, if you don't want then Thank You.

Comment: You can ask any question and I will try my best to answer it as well. But please keep one problem per thread. You're most welcome to ask a new question after this has been answered.